# How change EditText to listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, chat

I design chat app but I use sample but use EditText in sample for show message and no style for sender and receiver. I want to change EditText to list view or other TextView .

messaging java code :

```
public class Messaging extends Activity {

    private static final int MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT = 0;
    public String username;
    private EditText messageText;
    private EditText messageHistoryText;
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private TextView leftuser,leftmsg,rightuser,rightmsg;
    private IAppManager imService;
    private FriendInfo friend = new FriendInfo();
    private LocalStorageHandler localstoragehandler; 
    private Cursor dbCursor;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {



        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {          
            imService = ((IMService.IMBinder)service).getService();
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(Messaging.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        setContentView(R.layout.messaging_screen); //messaging_screen);

    messageHistoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);

        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);

        messageText.requestFocus();         

        sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();


        friend.userName = extras.getString(FriendInfo.USERNAME);
        friend.ip = extras.getString(FriendInfo.IP);
        friend.port = extras.getString(FriendInfo.PORT);
        String msg = extras.getString(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT);



        setTitle("messaging with" + friend.userName);


    //  EditText friendUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.friendUserName);
    //  friendUserName.setText(friend.userName);


        localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(this);
        dbCursor = localstoragehandler.get(friend.userName, IMService.USERNAME );

        if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0){
        int noOfScorer = 0;
        dbCursor.moveToFirst();
            while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())&&noOfScorer<dbCursor.getCount()) 
            {
                noOfScorer++;

                this.appendToMessageHistory(dbCursor.getString(2) , dbCursor.getString(3));
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        localstoragehandler.close();

        if (msg != null) 
        {
            this.appendToMessageHistory(friend.userName , msg);
            ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel((friend.userName+msg).hashCode());
        }

        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            CharSequence message;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                message = messageText.getText();
                if (message.length()>0) 
                {       
                    appendToMessageHistory(imService.getUsername(), message.toString());

                    localstoragehandler.insert(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message.toString());

                    messageText.setText("");
                    Thread thread = new Thread(){                   
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                if (imService.sendMessage(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message.toString()) == null)
                                {

                                    handler.post(new Runnable(){    

                                        public void run() {

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.message_cannot_be_sent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                            //showDialog(MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT);                                       
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.message_cannot_be_sent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }                       
                    };
                    thread.start();

                }

            }});

        messageText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {
                if (keyCode == 66){
                    sendMessageButton.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        int message = -1;
        switch (id)
        {
        case MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT:
            message = R.string.message_cannot_be_sent;
        break;
        }

        if (message == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(Messaging.this)       
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                }
            })        
            .create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
        unbindService(mConnection);

        FriendController.setActiveFriend(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {       
        super.onResume();
        bindService(new Intent(Messaging.this, IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(IMService.TAKE_MESSAGE);

        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, i);

        FriendController.setActiveFriend(friend.userName);      


    }


    public class  MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {       
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String username = extra.getString(MessageInfo.USERID);          
            String message = extra.getString(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT);

            if (username != null && message != null)
            {
                if (friend.userName.equals(username)) {
                    appendToMessageHistory(username, message);
                    localstoragehandler.insert(username,imService.getUsername(), message);

                }
                else {
                    if (message.length() > 15) {
                        message = message.substring(0, 15);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,  username + " says '"+
                                                    message + "'",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                }
            }           
        }

    };
    private MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();

    public  void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {


            messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\n");                                
            messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (localstoragehandler != null) {
            localstoragehandler.close();
        }
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            dbCursor.close();
        }
    }


}
```

and xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<!--    
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="Friend:"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/friendUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:editable="false" />
--> 
    <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:text="Messages:"/>

    <EditText  android:id="@+id/messageHistory"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="true"    
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarSize="10px"
                /> 

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="4">

            <EditText   android:id="@+id/message"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />

            <Button android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="Send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can not change the `EditText` object itself. What you can do is to replace that `EditText` with a new view:

```
//currentView is your EditText
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) currentView.getParent();
final int index = parent.indexOfChild(currentView);
removeView(currentView);
removeView(newView);
parent.addView(newView, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText.setFocusable(false);
EditText.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: This code removes the editing function of an EditText. Which turns it to an TextView